# Best way of pasting a lot of code into a question or answer?

Tags: discussion, support

What is the best way to copy large amounts of code into Stack Overflow?

For up to 10 lines, prepending 4 spaces to each line is ok.

For 50 or 100 lines it become a headache.

For more, this is probably not the correct way to do it.

What do you think?

Answer (score 8):

Select the snippet and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> or click the code button on the tool bar.  Or wrap the section with `<pre><code>` tags.

Also, I agree with the sentiment that if you have a *lot* of code, you're likely doing something wrong.  However, I disagree on what makes for a lot of code.  20 lines might not be very much.  If we're going to use lines for the metric, then 40 to 60 could still be reasonable.

Comment: Out of interest, can you find a question with 40-60 lines of code which could not have been simplified to narrow down the focus to the actual problem being explored? Maybe I've just seen too many "here's all my code, and there's a problem on line 1375" to remember the legitimate ones.

Comment: @Dominic: Are you assuming the code is in a question rather than an answer? I've certainly posted over 40 lines within an answer before, when I want to post a complete implementation to help the questioner - or a benchmark.

Comment: @Jon - Yes. Just reread the title and feeling a bit silly :-)

Answer (score 3):

Joel is right - you can hit Ctrl-K to indent a block of code *so long as it's not indented already*. If it's already indented, there's no way of indenting it *another* 4 spaces - it will be outdented instead.

Personally I'd like to see separate indent and outdent shortcut keys (probably keeping Ctrl-K with its current behaviour to avoid confusing people too much). As it is, I suspect either a greasemonkey script or manipulating the code elsewhere is the best way forward :(

Comment: You can un-indent just the first line, highlight the whole block, hit `ctrlK`, and it will push _everything_ over. Then fix the first line again. It's better than doing the whole thing line by line or pasting from an intermediary app first, anyway.

Comment: @Joel: Yes, I've done that before - but it's a pain if you're trying to add one block that needs to be indented 4 times or something like that. Better shortcut support would be much better IMO.

Answer (score 3):

Don't post hundreds of lines of code. Don't even post fifty. Abstract you problem down to a quantity that can be understood in short order: that is find the minium piece of source that will reproduce the problem.

Yes, this is some work, but

1. You might find the answer while you are doing it
2. It proves that your not asking *us* to read a pile of code because you are lazy.

---

And if you *are*, somehow, posting a long code for a good reason, select it a hit to `101010` button (or use `control-k` (which always screws me up with my emacs reflexes)).

Comment: Good point about trying to distil the problem down to the minimum reproducible code. I've found that this has worked for me in the past.

Answer (score 2):

I you would like to *supplement* your shortened example code, you can use a free service like [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/) to put your code and link to it in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you're not actually *writing* 50-100 lines of code in the Markdown editor. Especially if you're using a language where indentation matters.

When formatting code snippets for SO, I use an editor with indentation settings set at 2 spaces. This keeps lines short. And also makes it easy to indent everything by four spaces when I'm done...

Answer (score 1):

The best way in my opinion is the ["It's All Text!" plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4125) for firefox.
That way I can use gvim and get all the `>>` and `<<` goodness I'm used to.

The main drawback is the loss of the WYSIWYG stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got more than about 10 lines of code, your question is almost certainly too broad, certainly if you've got more than 20 lines of code.

Comment: An *answer* may reasonably contain that much code though - for example, a full collection class implementation.

Comment: I agree with Jon. Some do require a bit more code, but still can be to the point with the question.

Comment: @Jon Skeet - agreed. I know that I have a hard time not hitting back when I see a question with more than around 20 lines of code. It takes an act of the will (or an above usual amount of reluctance to do whatever it is I should really be doing ;-)) to read the question. Maybe that's just down to my tendency to prefer easy to digest questions - most of my visits to the site probably last around 5 minutes each.