# What is StackOverflow's policy on: Posting complete projects

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, source-code

Hey there,

I have a complete project that isn't functioning properly in IE.

I was wondering what SO's policies are on posting the entire project and letting people pick it apart?

Cheers.

Comment: Why not just post the particular areas that are not working in IE?

Comment: Probably a better question for meta.stackoverflow.com. But the response you'd probably get is: post the smallest set of code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Yep. This isn't a "fix my project" site, and such questions (in my experience) tend to be downvoted quite quickly. Well done for asking though...

Comment: That's cool, thank you for your answers - I was just curious :)

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of mine? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55986/how-much-code-is-too-much

Answer (score 5):

I think there's nothing speaking against linking to the entire project on an external location (like a github repository, pastebin.com or even a ZIP file).

Chances are, though, that nobody is actually going to pick through your project. "Fix my code" questions are generally not very well received on SO. The expectation is that you work through your project and identify the problems - I'mn sure the SO community will be happy to help you with those.

Comment: As long as you don't say "can somebody make this work", you're probably ok.  Most good questions, IMO, are the kind where someone has some code that doesn't work, they explain what they've done so far, post their non-working code, and ask for help in understanding why it doesn't work.  Usually, this ends up with an answer with working code or, at least, a pointer to the right direction to take to fix it.

Comment: I've never looked at the few zip-files posted at SO - i'd have to download them first, decompress, open in some viewer, ... Online viewable sources have a *much* higher chance of people looking at them.

Comment: My experience is that "fix my code" questions attract answers (at least in C and C++) provided the OP posts a reasonable amount of code (enough to show all necessary context, not enough to be overwhelming), has at least one specific problem, and shows signs of having worked on the program.

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of StackOverflow's policies, people aren't going to take very well to you posting a ton of code in a question.  In addition, asking someone to fix your whole project seems too much like asking me to do your work for you.  Narrow down the problem to the smallest bit of code that seems to be causing the problem(s).  This is good debugging practice anyway.  If in the process you solve the problem, great.  If not, post a question about that tiny bit.  Likely, you'll get an answer that helps and then you move on to the next bit.

Answer (score 1):

I think the policy is: *don't*