# What is the best way to post a code here in stackoverflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way of pasting a lot of code into a question or answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25624/best-way-of-pasting-a-lot-of-code-into-a-question-or-answer)

To add code in my posting I have to manually add five white spaces as we all did...
But it gets really annoying if I have a long lines of codes..What do you guys do with this?

Comment: Shouldn't this be on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/)?

Comment: Looks like duplicate of: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25624/best-way-of-pasting-a-lot-of-code-into-a-question-or-answer

Answer (score 4):

Select the code and then hit the button above the edit box that looks like "{}".

Comment: Or use CTRL-K if you don't want the hassle of finding your mouse.

Answer (score 1):

Just enter you code in without the spaces, then select all the lines and click the `{ }` button in the editor toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

You could just link to it on pastebin. Not an elegant solution but it works easily enough.

Answer (score 0):

You should **always** try and paste the code into here, but you can always use something like [paste bin](http://pastebin.com/).