# Best way to copy and paste code into a post

Tags: discussion, posts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

This is my very first post on SO and I have a quick question... In order to post a code block it says to indent by four spaces. Does this mean I have to indent every line of code 4 spaces? I feel like I'm missing something here. What's the best way to just copy and paste some code (java and xml) into a post and have it blocked and formatted (without having to edit each and every line I've pasted)???

Comment: Select the code and click the `{}` button. See [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: Refer to this **[EDITING HELP](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)** and **[Best way of pasting a lot of code into a question or answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/25627/171616)**

Comment: Why do so many people have trouble with this? What can we do to make the bouncing formatting help *more* noticeable? `<blink>`?

Comment: @TheEstablishment: Apparently we need Clippycorn back.

Comment: @TheEstablishment, for me personally it's not clear that I must **first** paste a code block and only **then** press the tool button. When you do in such order, the code becomes messed up just after pasting and this is confusing, and prevents people from continuation. When you do other way - press the button first and then paste - only first line of code becomes formatted properly and all the others must be idented manually. This can be improved, imho, that is SO should format all new text entered into empty idented position if it's just created by pressing the button. May be feature request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paste the code into the text area then highlight the code and click on the Code Sample `{}` button.

See [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)